# Julia dataframe replace character in column

Tags: replace, julia

I am working on a dataframe in julia and one column has zipcodes. In certain instances, a State code is appended in front of zip code.

For example: if zipcode is `123456`, and state is `ab`, it looks like `ab 123456`.

There are multiple values like that in the column. How can I replace all `"ab "` with `""` in that column.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `replace` function with a regexp matching your pattern and broadcast it over all entries of the column like this:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(x = ["ab x", "y", "ab z"])
3×1 DataFrame 
 Row │ x      
     │ String 
─────┼────────
   1 │ ab x   
   2 │ y      
   3 │ ab z   

julia> df.x .= replace.(df.x, r"^ab " => "")
3-element Vector{String}:
 "x"
 "y"
 "z"

julia> df
3×1 DataFrame
 Row │ x      
     │ String 
─────┼────────
   1 │ x
   2 │ y
   3 │ z
```

Comment: If the "state" is "always two letters", then one might generalize the regex (for many states' incorrect entries) with something like `r"^[a-z][a-z] "` or similar pattern (might modify slightly for case-insensitivity)..

Comment: Agreed - any valid regex can be used.

Comment: Is there a similar command for replacing integer values?

Comment: It is the same, e.g. `replace([1,2,3,1], 1 => 10)` if you want to replace all `1`s with `10`s - if this is what you wanted.